# How can I include a JS file with query string in <h:outputScript>?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

In JSF page I use this code to include a JS file:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="reworkBase.js" />
```

It works well, but I want to implement cache busting by adding a version parameter:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="reworkBase.js?version=1" />
```

But the JS file will not be found. I know it also works well if I use the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag. But is there any way to implement with `<h:outputScript>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in Mojarra. Their `ScriptRenderer` was as per [issue 1212](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1212) fixed to support query strings. However, their fix was wrong for the case a `library` is specified. They used `+` instead of `&amp;` as query string parameter separator, which only results in 404's:

```xml
<script src="/context/javax.faces.resource/reworkBase.js.xhtml?ln=js+version=1">
```

It should have been:

```xml
<script src="/context/javax.faces.resource/reworkBase.js.xhtml?ln=js&amp;version=1">
```

I've reported this bug as [issue 2168](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2168).

In the meanwhile your best bet is to just omit the `library` altogether, given the library name of `js` (which obviously stands for "JavaScript") you seem not to be interested in using configureable look'n'feel/scripting libraries at all.

```xml
<h:outputScript name="js/reworkBase.js?version=1" />
```

This will result in the right URL.

```xml
<script src="/context/javax.faces.resource/js/reworkBase.js.xhtml?version=1">
```

Comment: I tried `<h:outputScript name="js/myJsFile.js" />`, and it results in `<script src="/context/javax.faces.resource/js/myJsFile.js">`. No `.xhtml?version=1` part. What do I need to do for that part to show up?

Comment: Sorry, the example in my answer was bad, you should be adding `?version=1` to the `name` :) I edited the answer. The key point is to just omit the `library`.

Comment: @BheshG: Are you the questioner? It's a different user account?

Comment: Sorry. I am not. I just found it interesting so. Sorry if I confused you.