# @ResourceDependency with string query

Tags: jsf, resources, java-ee-6, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I want to implement cache busting via string query with the file version, but I also want to use @ResourceDependency. So this is what I have:

```
@ResourceDependency(name = "scrypt.js?v=version", library = "mylib", target = "head")
```

I know mojarra had trouble with string queries before for the `<f:outputScript>`, but this has been fixed ([stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102695/how-can-i-include-a-js-file-with-query-string-in-houtputscript)). But apparently they never really supported string queries for the annotation.

The problem is in `ResourceDependencyHandler#createComponentResource`. It calls `ResourceHandler#getRendererTypeForResourceName` that returns `null` if the `name` provided has a string query attached to it. This actually goes back all the way to `ServletContext#getMimeType`. That is the guy who can't realize the mime type is `application/javascript` when there is a query string attached to the file name.

Does anybody knows a workaround for this? I'm currently working with Mojarra 2.2.8.

Thank you.

---

The fully qualified names of the classes I mentioned:

```
com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ResourceDependencyHandler
javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler
```

Comment: Apparently there is no solution for that. They came up with the idea of having one single annotation for Javascript and CSS files instead of one different annotation for each resource type (like <h:outputScript> and <h:outputStylesheet>), so they rely on ServletContext#getMimeType to figure out the content type. The sad thing is that ServletContext#getMimeType implementations normally do not know how to handle query strings (i.e. "?v=version"), thus breaking the whole thing.

Comment: I think that could be a workaround to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268345/how-can-i-implement-css-versioning-to-solve-cache-issues-using-jsf-2-houtpu

Comment: @Tarik Thank you so much! I didn't know about the <resource-handler> decorator. I used it to point to my own ResourceHandler implementation, where I overrode getRendererTypeForResourceName so it could handle query strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question based on @Tarik's comment.

I added this to my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
  <resource-handler>my.package.MyResourceHandlerImplementation</resource-handler>
</application>
```

`MyResourceHandlerImplementation` looks like this:

```
import com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl;

public class MyResourceHandlerImplementation extends ResourceHandlerImpl {

    @Override
    public String getRendererTypeForResourceName(String resourceName) {
        if (hasQueryString(resourceName)) {
            resourceName = removeQueryString(resourceName);
        }
        return super.getRendererTypeForResourceName(resourceName);
    }

    private boolean hasQueryString(String resourceName) {
        return resourceName.indexOf('?') != -1;
    }

    private String removeQueryString(String resourceName) {
        return resourceName.substring(0, resourceName.indexOf('?'));
    }

}
```

And this is how you make `@ResourceDependency` support query strings (thus supporting cache busting).

Comment: This code worked perfectly for me, although I'm extending javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper instead.